# How to list only nodes which are master from kubectl output?

Tags: kubectl

```
]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                            STATUS                     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready                      master   300d   v1.15.3
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready                      node     180d   v1.15.3
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready                      master   300d   v1.15.3
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready                      node     300d   v1.15.3
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready                      node     300d   v1.15.3
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   node     180d   v1.15.3
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready                      node     180d   v1.15.3
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready                      master   300d   v1.15.3
ip<IP>.ec2.internal   Ready                      node     300d   v1.15.3
```

What I want is the output should have only list of node name showing which is first column and which are master only. I tried the script way:

```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl get nodes --selector=node-role.kubernetes.io/master > nodelist.txt
cat nodelist.txt
while IFS=" " read -r f1
do
 echo $f1
done < nodelist.txt
```

, But I want any method using kubectl --custom-column or json filtering plz suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use [labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) and jsonpath to select anything you need from `kubectl get nodes -o json` output

```
kubectl get nodes -l node-role.kubernetes.io/master -o 'jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name}'
```

btw, you could you [kubernetes kubectl Cheat Sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) if you lost at any point. It has most frequently used commands

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this but it should give you the output you want.

```
kubectl get nodes | grep master | awk 'print {$1 $3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I want any method using kubectl --custom-column or json filtering plz suggest.

Yes, you can use a `--custom-columns` to only show the name

```
kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name
NAME
my-node
```

In addition, you can omit the headers using `--no-headers`

```
kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name --no-headers
my-node
```

Using the selector you provided, to only show master nodes, the full command is this:

```
kubectl get nodes --selector=node-role.kubernetes.io/master -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name --no-headers
```